# obtain number from string in matlab

Tags: matlab, find

I have an array of strings:

```
dd = {'L','temp1','temp23','Reas'};
```

I would like to extract the numbers from the strings that contain any numbers (if that makes sense). So, the solution for this question should be 1 and 23.

How can I achieve this in matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's part of the solution.  Suppose

```
myString = 'temp23'
```

then the expression

```
str2double(a(isstrprop(a,'digit')))
```

will return

```
23
```

I haven't got the time to turn this into a function to deal with your array of strings but this should get you started.

@DennisJahruddin suggested the following completion of my answer.  I haven't tested it thoroughly:

```
dd = {'L','temp1','temp23','Reas'};
ee = cellfun(@(a) str2double(a(isstrprop(a,'digit'))),dd);
ff = ee(~isnan(ee))
```

Comment: Nice to see `isstrprop` in action. Hope you don't mind that I updated the answer.

Comment: I didn't object to your edit, but others did and it was rejected before I reviewed it so I edited my answer myself.