# extracting part of specific line from csv in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a csv file with the third line as `c 150`. I can read the line using

```
c_raw = rawData(3, 1)
```

The output in this case is `'c 150'`. I'm not sure how to code it so that I get only `150` as a numeric value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278364/obtain-number-from-string-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

if possible you can post process the input using regexp.

```
c = regexpi(c_raw, '\s(\d+)', 'tokens')
str2num((c{:}{:}))
```

hope this helps.